# Need an alternative to Comodo Firewall

Tags: gratis, windows-7, firewall

Please note: This is NOT a duplicate of earlier questions of this sort. As of 2017, market landscape has changed; most solutions historically recommended got discontinued or made paid only.

So. After spending the whole yesterday fixing the consequences of a Comodo Firewall update, I decided to look for an alternative. What I need is:

1. Something able to run on Windows 7 SP1 64-bit.
2. Free. I'm not paying my bucks for a tool that can break any moment like Comodo did.
3. Alerts and rules for incoming and outgoing connections. Glasswire won't do; its free version is merely a traffic indicator.
4. Not just an UI for the built-in Windows firewall.
5. Supported. This part rules out Outpost, Privatefirewall and many other once great solutions.

Not overly worried about HIPS and such. Can live with a complicated interface. Resource consumption is not an issue - it's an i7 rig. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you really concerned about security?  Software loaded into windows could possible be bypassed by root kits or etc.  Have you considered loading OpenWrt, ddwrt, or similar into a hardware router?

Comment: @cybernard This very machine is our home network router, besides other things. Hardware routers powerful enough to handle the bandwidth we (sometimes) need are prohibitively expensive.

Comment: I loaded the free version of VMware server, and have a linux OS with iptables as my solution.  PFsense might be a better linux OS solution for you.  Make your Windows 7 a virtual machine inside vmware.  Openwrt and etc are compatible with many $100 routers.  Unless you have google fibre as your ISP keeping up shouldn't be a problem.  Unless you have dozen of complex alerts.  Unless your running a web server or etc, your incoming, from ISP, rules should be allow existing connections, and drop everything else.

Comment: @cybernard Well, I think I could come up with this or that heterogeneous solution, but what we have now has been serving us faithfully for years until yesterday. Just replacing the firewall would do. Maybe I'll try to find the old version of Comodo - the one they tried to update and broke it instead - if everything else fails.